# Django admin TabularInline "502 Bad Gateway” nginx prematurely closed connection

Tags: django, nginx

I have seen lot of discussion on this but nothing has helped. Below is the error I am getting

```
*9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

It is happening with my Django TabularInline admin view. Everything else working absolutely fine.

It is working if I do this change in TargetTabularInline,

```
fields = (‘reviewed’,)
```

I believe the issue is because Target model has person foreign key on some other table. Which is where it is getting time out. Please advise how can I solve this?

admin.py

```
class TargetTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Target


class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TargetTabularInline]
    list_display = ['title', 'source', 'reviewed', 'category', 'sfw']
    search_fields = ('title', 'category', 'source__name', 'reviewed', )

    class Meta:
        model = Video

admin.site.register(Video, VideoAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class Video(DFModel):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, models.DO_NOTHING)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Creator, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    views = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    page_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    video_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    thumb_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sfw = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    organization_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

class Target(DFModel):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(
        'Video', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = ‘target'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Person model (or Creator) might have too many entries, which the admin tries to load in the drop down menu when viewing a specific entry in the admin details page dashboard, which causes too much load on the server

You could add this to the VideoAdmin class

```
raw_id_fields = ("creator",)
# OR
readonly_fields = ('creator',)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

This won't load the whole creator table which will reduce the load on your server,
 and the workers will be free to server other requests.

Add this to your Target admin also, if there are too many entries in the Person table.